# "Time out" exception trying to configure SMTP for Sentry

Tags: python, sentry

I am self-hosting Sentry on Ubuntu and stuck trying to configure outbound email following these instructions: https://docs.getsentry.com/on-premise/server/config/. I tried multiple SMTP servers and accounts - everything yields "Connection unexpectedly closed: timed out" when I try to test the settings on the /manage/status/mail/ page. I was able to successfully send email using my settings with smtplib for Python. I would appreciate any advice on what the cause and a possible fix might be. Where can I find Sentry's log files?